# Troubleshooting PHP PDO Prepare statement binding

Tags: php, pdo

Here we go. I am still pretty new to PHP, and I'm trying to learn PDO. I'm trying to figure out why

```
$validStartYear=-1;
echo $listString; //$listString = 'WHERE a regexp "Nissan"'
$queryToPrep='SELECT a FROM b WHERE a regexp "Nissan" ORDER BY start_year asc LIMIT 1;';
$query = $newMysql->prepare($queryToPrep);
$query->execute();
echo '<br/><br/>';
print_r($query);
echo '<br/>';
$row=$query->fetch();
echo $row[0],'<br/>';
```

outputs

```
a regexp "Nissan"

PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT a FROM b WHERE a regexp "Nissan" ORDER BY start_year asc LIMIT 1; )
1971
```

while

```
$prepAgain='SELECT a FROM b WHERE ? ORDER BY a asc LIMIT 1;';
$query2= $newMysql->prepare($prepAgain);
$query2->bindParam(1, $listString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query2->execute();
echo '<br/>';
print_r($query2);
echo '<br/>';
$row2=$query2->fetch();
echo $row2[0];
```

outputs

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT start_year FROM engine_kits WHERE ? ORDER BY start_year asc LIMIT 1; )
```

no value is returned. I get an empty array, no matter how big I go. The syntax seems correct, but am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot replace any arbitrary component of a SQL string with `?` placeholders.  I'm not sure if PDO supports placeholders for `REGEXP`, but if it does, it will need to be something like `WHERE a regexp ?`

Comment: So what is the value of $listString?

Comment: Why do you need `REGEXP` here?

Comment: had to edit to show that my `REGEXP` used quotes. I am using `REGEXP` here because the value I'm looking for could be something like `Ford Mazda`, so `a = b` won't work. Possible better way?

Comment: @Michael So I would need to have a single word string, or something of the sort to bind into the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind the actual values via PDO. Your first code block works because nothing is being incorrectly binded. Also, you're usually going to want to use bindValue() instead of bindParam().

Try something like this

```
$car = 'Nissan'
$sql = 'SELECT a FROM b WHERE a regexp ? ORDER BY a asc LIMIT 1';
$stmnt = $newMysql->prepare( $sql );
$stmnt->bindValue( 1, $car, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```